# When installing ROS melodic I keep getting this error 'E: Unable to locate package ros-melodic-desktop-full'

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When trying to install ROS melodic via the instructions from the wiki ([link text](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu) i keep getting to step 1.4 and receiving a

```
E:Unable to locate package ros-melodic-desktop-full
```

message.

Step 1.3 yields this:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-key 421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116    
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.gR0QjhB4Rp/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-key 421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116    
gpg: key 5523BAEEB01FA116: "ROS Builder <rosbuild@ros.org>" not changed    
gpg: Total number processed: 1    
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

Step 1.4 yields this:

```
$ sudo apt-get update

Get:1 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic InRelease [242 kB]    
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                         
Get:3 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]              
Get:4 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]             
Ign:5 http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise-updates/grizzly InRelease
Hit:6 http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise-updates/grizzly Release
Hit:7 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic InRelease                          
Get:8 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic/universe Sources [9,051 kB]    
Get:10 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic/main Sources [829 kB]    
Get:11 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic/multiverse Sources [181 kB]    
Get:12 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic/restricted Sources [5,324 B]    
Get:13 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages [1,007 kB]    
Get:14 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic/main Translation-en [516 kB]    
Get:15 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic/main i386 DEP-11 Metadata [477 kB]    
Get:16 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [118 kB]    
Get:17 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [245 kB]    
Get:18 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic/restricted i386 Packages [9,156 B]    
Get:19 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic/restricted Translation-en [3,584 B]    
Get:20 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages [8,531 kB]    
Get:21 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic/universe Translation-en [4,941 kB]    
Get:22 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 DEP-11 Metadata [3,283 kB]    
Get:23 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [2,151 kB]    
Get:24 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [8,420 kB]    
Get:25 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic/multiverse i386 Packages [144 kB]    
Get:26 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic/multiverse Translation-en [108 kB]    
Get:27 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic/multiverse i386 DEP-11 Metadata [50.6 kB]    
Get:28 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic/multiverse DEP-11 48x48 Icons [8,931 B]    
Get:29 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons [225 kB]    
Get:30 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe Sources [52.2 kB]    
Get:31 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic-updates/main Sources [152 kB]    
Get:32 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse Sources [2,676 B]    
Get:33 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages [252 kB]    
Get:34 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic-updates/main Translation-en [105 kB]    
Get:35 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 DEP-11 Metadata [138 kB]    
Get:36 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [31.4 kB]    
Get:37 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [53.7 kB]    
Get:38 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages [157 kB]    
Get:39 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe Translation-en [71.0 kB]    
Get:40 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 DEP-11 Metadata [149 kB]
Get:41 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [159 kB]    
Get:42 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [266 kB]    
Get:43 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [3,924 B]    
Get:44 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse Translation-en [2,376 B]
Get:45 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse i386 DEP-11 Metadata [2,464 B]
Get:46 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse DEP-11 48x48 Icons [29 B]    
Get:47 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons [2,638 B]
Get:48 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic-security/main Sources [39.3 kB]    
Get:49 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse Sources [1,336 B]    
Get:50 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic-security/universe Sources [13.1 kB]    
Get:51 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic-security/main i386 Packages [109 kB]    
Get:52 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic-security/main Translation-en [52.2 kB]    
Get:53 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic-security/main i386 DEP-11 Metadata [204 B]    
Get:54 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic-security/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [29 B]    
Get:55 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [29 B]    
Get:56 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic-security/universe i386 Packages [48.5 kB]    
Get:57 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic-security/universe Translation-en [27.4 kB]    
Get:58 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic-security/universe i386 DEP-11 Metadata [5,792 B]
Get:59 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [6,960 B]
Get:60 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [8,064 B]
Get:61 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse i386 Packages [1,604 B]
Get:62 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse Translation-en [996 B]

Fetched 42.6 MB in 8s (5,039 kB/s)                                             

Reading package lists... Done

W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:55    
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:55    
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:55    
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:55    
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-i386.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:55    
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:55    
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:55    
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:55    
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-i386) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:55    
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:55    
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:55    
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:55    
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:55    
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:55    
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-i386.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:55    
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:55    
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:55    
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:55    
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-i386) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:55    
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:55
```

And then this:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-desktop-full

Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-melodic-desktop-full
```

I've tried solutions from this site and others and nothing has worked so far. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and inputting the previously mentioned commands into the terminal.

Edit:

1. I honestly can't remember everything I've tried to do.
2. How do i clean up apt sources?
3. 

```
lsb_release -a
```

results in:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

and

```
uname -a
```

results in:

```
Linux iram4-desktop 4.15.0-30-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 26 17:40:03 UTC 2018 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300054/when-installing-ros-melodic-i-keep-getting-this-error-%27e:-unable-to-locate-package-ros-melodic-desktop-full%27/) by [George_Drone](https://answers.ros.org/users/36893/george_drone/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-08-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2018-08-08**:
"I've tried solutions from this site and others and nothing has worked so far" does not tell us enough. Be specific about what you tried so we can avoid repeating advice.

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2018-08-08**:
It looks like your apt sources are a bit of a mess. You should clean up the cause of those warnings first.

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2018-08-08**:
What architecture are you running? You need to be on `amd64`, `arm64` or `armhf`. Please post the output of `lsb_release -a` and `uname -a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your architecture is i686, which is 32-bit. ROS Melodic only supports amd64, which is 64-bit. It is complaining that it can't find the package because the package does not exist for your architecture.

You need to install the 64-bit version of Ubuntu first. Then you will be able to install ROS.

If you really must use a 32-bit architecture, you will need to [install ROS from source](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Source). It's not hard, but it will take a long time to compile everything.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2018-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [George_Drone](https://answers.ros.org/users/36893/george_drone/) on 2018-08-10**:
Thank you for your help.I did try to install from source but I ran into separate issues, at this point I think I'll just switch to the 64-bit version. Is there a good tutorial that you could suggest on how to go from 32-bit to 64-bit? I'm dual booting windows and ubuntu.

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2018-08-12**:
Converting to 64-bit would not be impossible, but it would be very complicated. I think it would be faster to reinstall Ubuntu.